# Subtract array with different size in R

Tags: arrays, r

Let `A` and `B` be arrays, of dimension `[3,4,5]` and `[4,5]`, respectively.

E.g.,

```
A <- array(100,c(3, 4,5))
B <- array(80,    c(4,5))
```

My desired answer is an array `C` of dimension `[3,4,5]` such that

```
C[i,j,k] = A[i,j,k] - B[j,k]
```

for all `i,j,k`

---

***Edit*** Which answer is fastest code?

To evaluate the following three answers, I executed the following code to quantify the time of the three codes.
The result is the following;

```
> mb
Unit: microseconds
 expr  min    lq   mean median    uq   max neval
   f1 28.4 33.00 37.329  34.75 37.00 213.5   100
   f2 32.5 37.65 40.069  38.95 40.55 103.0   100
   f3 33.8 40.25 42.397  41.65 43.30  64.5   100
```

Thus the `f1` is the most faster, thus I choose the answer of `@user10488504` as an answer of this question.
Thank you, three persons `@user10488504`, `@Stéphane Laurent` and `@Lyngbakr`. I will use your suggesting code in my package. It helps me very much.
[image]
***Code, which calculates running times.***

```
f1 <- function(){
A <- array(1:100, c(3, 4, 5))
B <- array(1:80, c(4,5))

C <- array(aperm(sapply(1:dim(A)[1], function(i) A[i,,] - B)), dim(A))

}


f2<-function(){

A <- array(1:100, c(3, 4, 5))
B <- array(1:80, c(4,5))
sweep(A, c(2,3), B)
}

f3 <- function(){

A <- array(1:100, c(3, 4, 5))
B <- array(1:80, c(4,5))

# Perform calculation
res <- array(t(apply(A, MARGIN = 1, function(x)x-B)), c(3, 4, 5))
}


library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

mb <- microbenchmark(
  f1 = f1(),
  f2 = f2(),
  f3 = f3()
)

mb
autoplot(mb)
```

Comment: Does this not work out of the box? (i.e. can't you just give the command `A-B`)? If it doesn't it's probably just an ordering issue.

Comment: `A-B` did not work. I converted `A` to  `AA` so that the first and the second dimension is equal to `B`, but it also did not work. The conversion is done by `AA <-aperm(A,c(2,3,1))`

Comment: In that case `sweep` is your function.

Comment: You can always use `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you for reply, @yamabrina. Of course, `for` is available, ... if possible I do not want to use it, but I want to use vectorization.

Comment: Thank you @JDL. Thank you for letting me know the `sweep`, I do not know it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `sapply` and `aperm` like:

```
C <- array(aperm(sapply(1:dim(A)[1], function(i) A[i,,] - B)), dim(A))
```

Answer (score 5):

With `sweep`:

```
A <- array(1:100, c(3, 4, 5))
B <- array(1:80, c(4,5))
> sweep(A, c(2,3), B)
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    2    4    6
[2,]    1    3    5    7
[3,]    2    4    6    8

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    8   10   12   14
[2,]    9   11   13   15
[3,]   10   12   14   16

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   16   18   20   22
[2,]   17   19   21   23
[3,]   18   20   22   24

, , 4

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   24   26   28   30
[2,]   25   27   29   31
[3,]   26   28   30   32

, , 5

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   32   34   36   38
[2,]   33   35   37   39
[3,]   34   36   38   40
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, `sweep` is quite new for me, I try to understand your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt that uses `apply`.

```r
# Define arrays
A <- array(1:100, c(3, 4, 5))
B <- array(1:80, c(4,5))

# Perform calculation
res <- array(t(apply(A, MARGIN = 1, function(x)x-B)), c(3, 4, 5))

# Check result
res[1,,]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    0    8   16   24   32
#> [2,]    2   10   18   26   34
#> [3,]    4   12   20   28   36
#> [4,]    6   14   22   30   38
A[1,,] - B
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    0    8   16   24   32
#> [2,]    2   10   18   26   34
#> [3,]    4   12   20   28   36
#> [4,]    6   14   22   30   38
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for reply, I need  time to understand your code.